# Where are face attributes defined for the `*Agenda Commands*` buffer?

Tags: faces, org-agenda

I'm trying to modify some face attributes in the buffer that appears when the `org-agenda` command is called. This buffer displays `*Agenda Commands*` and `Fundamental` (mode) in the mode line. I've tried modifying `fundamental-mode` face attributes but to no avail. Also, I can't seem to run the `what-cursor-position` function (i.e., `C-u C-x =`) like I normally would to find out more information regarding buffer properties--any one keystroke closes this buffer.

What properties is this buffer calling on?

Comment: Type `M-x find-function RET org-agenda-get-restriction-and-command RET` after **first** having loaded the `org-agenda.el` library.  The text-properties are hard-coded.  You can use the same type of procedure as in a recent thread of yours -- e.g., `(require 'org-agenda) (defun org-agenda-get-restriction-and-command (prefix-descriptions) . . . )` to modify the substantive components of the function (if you so choose).  Alternatively, you can adjust the faces globally or buffer locally for the faces currently being used by said function -- same methods as indicated in the recent thread of yours.

Comment: That's just what I needed. Thanks, @lawlist!

Comment: @lawlist: Please post it as an answer. OP: if this answer is satisfactory, please consider accepting it (once posted), so that the question no longer appears in the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: `M-x` `find-face-definition` `org-agenda-anything`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary function responsible for creating the `*Agenda Commands*` buffer is located within the `org-agenda.el` library, and is called `org-agenda-get-restriction-and-command`.  The function at issue can be found in the source code by typing `M-x find-function RET org-agenda-get-restriction-and-command RET` *after* first having loaded the `org-agenda.el` library -- e.g., `M-x eval-expression RET (require 'org-agenda) RET`.  The text-properties for the faces are hard-coded.

If the original poster decides to modify the function directly, the function can be copied and pasted to the `.emacs` file with a *preceding* `require` statement for the library where the original function is located.  Although the internal workings of the function may be modified by the original poster, the original function will maintain its original name -- e.g., `(require 'org-agenda) (defun org-agenda-get-restriction-and-command (prefix-descriptions) . . . )`.

Options include, but are not limited to, hard-coding different faces defined by the original poster, changing the global settings for the existing faces used by the function, or including code to use the existing faces on a buffer-local basis (with different attributes) with something like `face-remap-add-relative`, the documentation for which is at the following link:  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Face-Remapping.html